# Does Lumosity increase your intelligence?

Tags: neurology, intelligence, cognitive-fitness, cognitive-science

[Lumosity](http://lumosity.com) is a popular website that claims to help you become a more intellectually capable individual.

> Harness your brain's neuroplasticity and train your way to a brighter life"

- Is it truly possible to improve your IQ?
- Is IQ a good measure of Intelligence?
- Are they actually onto something, like PositScience?

Here are some studies I have found that Lumosity use to support their claims:

- [New Approaches to Learning Using Neuroscience and Gaming:
  A large scale, multi-site implementation of a web-based cognitive training program in academic settings](http://cdn.beacon.lumosity.com/assets/hcp/Ng-2012-L&B_poster_revised-ab5be2fb53ea918f0a1fa6e413be884d.pdf)
- [Enhancing visual attention and working memory with a Web-based cognitive training program](http://static.sl.lumosity.com/pdf/hardy_drescher_sarkar_kellet_scanlon_2011.pdf)
- [Changes in frontal-parietal activation and math skills performance following adaptive number sense training: preliminary results from a pilot study.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21714745?dopt=Abstract)

Lumosity has a user-community of over 35 million. There are likely to be duplicates and bots though but that is quite surprising. They seem to be amassing great profits and there are testimonies but those are only anecdotal evidence and not part of a well researched statistical study, and may even be fabricated.

Comment: Be careful: The question has a few false dichotomies in it. e.g. IQ may be well-defined AND impossible to improve. They could not be a scam AND not be onto something. There could be worthless testimonials that AREN'T fabricated.

Comment: Yes, that would be significantly probable, thank you.

Comment: +1, I have already asked this question http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2135/is-there-someone-allergic-to-lumosity but due to some criticisms I then deleted it.

Comment: @Carlo_R: Ah! That explains why I couldn't find the duplicate question. I *knew* this had been asked before...

Comment: Yes, you may have asked that question already but it was not answered and you deleted it. Therefore, my "duplicate" question - which justifiably is not and should remain in tact - should not be removed (if that was even a threat to begin with). Also, I have had no knowledge of this "duplicate" question. I am quite sure that it should be fine to ask a question again if it had not been answered and in fact, down-voted. There is no reason to bring that into here.

Comment: @TheRouge relax I don't think Carlo intended to say you somehow copied the question, it looks to me like he is just reinforcing that this is a complete acceptable question.

Comment: I apologize if I may seem offensive in my reply. That is not my intention, just a misinterpretation. I just wanted to clarify.

Comment: Rouge, yes, @isJustMe is right. I like your question and, in fact, upvoted it :) And don't worry for the rest, here we all are happy people!

Comment: The website does not appear to claim it improves one's intelligence. It claims to improve certain cognitive processes. From my understanding of the definitions, these are not the same things, though closely related. Perhaps the question should be re-worded slightly? FWIW, I just started a trail of their training, I'm not convinced so far what is gained on the site translates to real world situations.

Comment: @Carlo - Thank you! Okay. :)
Oh and bcworkz - That is true. I just felt that since those factors have a nearly unmistakable correlation with intelligence that the question would suffice for all areas. I am quite sure that since Lumosity cannot directly claim that their programs increase overall intelligence they focus on specific areas which may give the impression of affecting IQ due to the ambiguity of the term intelligence. For what its worth, I have tried the program as well. In fact, I have spent weeks training and felt that if I had made gains they were not even minutely significant.

Comment: Anecdotally, I get better at taking IQ tests when I practice taking IQ tests.  So I'm pretty sure it's possible to "improve your IQ" as measured by an IQ test.

Comment: @RexKerr of course, as with all multiple-guess tests, you can train yourself for them. There's an entire industry that survives on just that, preparing people for corporate "assessment centers" which are in principle exactly the same as "IQ tests".

Comment: I have to agree with @bcworkz . When I took my first General Ability Test, I failed. After some studying I passed with good grades. After more studying, I received an ESIP scholarship for students with "high IQ". Was I that smart? No. I just had exam smarts. Also, it seems that the smartest man in the world (by IQ) does the same thing. He spends up to [120 hours a week](http://www.businessinsider.com/the-man-with-the-highest-iq-in-the-world-doesnt-think-hes-very-smart-at-all-2012-4?IR=T&) practising IQ tests.

Comment: @TwilightSparkle That doesn't leave much time for anything else. Only 48 hours left for the whole week. That's less than 7 hours. Does he sleep? I'm not sure I believe him. Reminds me of another guy I was talking to earlier that insisted that he does work and school for 100 hours a week  still gets 8 hours sleep. Possible, but I just don't believe him. It leaves less than two hours a day to do all the other stuff you need to do, like eat, bathe, drive to places, grocery shop, etc.

Comment: @fredsbend Yeah, I think he probably means that he does intensive 120 hours a week training to prepare for a test but there's no way that he can do it every day of the year.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### The Scientific Consensus: No evidence they reduce cognitive decline

In October 2014, a [consensus statement](http://longevity3.stanford.edu/blog/2014/10/15/the-consensus-on-the-brain-training-industry-from-the-scientific-community/) was produced that rejected the key claims about brain games. The list of signatories include Susanne Jaeggi, Michael Kane, Randy Engle, Hal Pashler and a number of other people who can be considered eminent in this field (and who you'll find cited below).

> We object to the claim that brain games offer consumers a scientifically grounded avenue to reduce or reverse cognitive decline when there is no compelling scientific evidence to date that they do. The promise of a magic bullet detracts from the best evidence to date, which is that cognitive health in old age reflects the long-term effects of healthy, engaged lifestyles. In the judgment of the signatories below, exaggerated and misleading claims exploit the anxieties of older adults about impending cognitive decline. We encourage continued careful research and validation in this field.

#### Is it truly possible to improve your IQ?

No, all brain and IQ training games we know are bogus. Here's what's been discussed on this platform so far: [Sudoku](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1032/does-solving-sudoku-puzzles-improve-your-mental-abilities), [video games](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8233/does-playing-popular-video-games-improve-a-childs-iq),

- It's reflected in the fact that the Jaeggi et al. study, purportedly showing a transfer effect from dual N-back working memory training to fluid IQ, (http://www.psychfiledrawer.org/top-20/) is the number one of studies that researchers on Psychfiledrawer.com want to see replicated. Here is a [takedown by Engle et al.](http://www.ingentaconnect.com/content/acad/psyb/2010/00000050/f0020003/art00007). Here's a [great blog post by Ed Yong](http://phenomena.nationalgeographic.com/2013/07/09/nice-results-but-what-did-you-expect/) on some of the trouble with these studies (it's not the only big problem though, don't believe Schubert for one minute).
- Transfer effects have been [found not to replicate](http://psychology.gatech.edu/renglelab/publications/2012/Redicketal2012.pdf) [several times](http://www.frontiersin.org/cognition/10.3389/fpsyg.2013.00031/abstract?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Psychology-w6-2013). Here's the most [recent failure to replicate and a critical review](http://psycnet.apa.org/journals/xge/142/2/359/).
- It's an old topic, obviously many people tried to raise IQ and failed.
- There have been numerous clones of the same idea, the ones with the most profile are Lumosity, Cogmed and Jaeggi's program (I think this is marketed the least but best-known to academics, Lumosity may be the opposite, I think they don't have ambitions for peer review).
- Here is a [takedown of Lumosity's "research](http://thestochasticman.wordpress.com/2009/02/26/why-brain-training-doesnt-work/). 23 people are in that sample. Thirty-five million users, you say? Don't know what happened there... He also links to reports of Lumosity using scammy invoicing.
- For good measure, a [funny secondhand blogpost on the topic](http://www.ironmanmode.com/archives/5736), an [article in the New Yorker](http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/elements/2013/04/brain-games-are-bogus.html) and [another takedown titled "The new Snakeoil"](http://psychcentral.com/blog/archives/2012/06/05/the-new-snake-oil-brain-training-brain-fitness/).

#### Is IQ a good measure of Intelligence?

[Yes, pretty good](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence_quotient#Reliability_and_validity), but many people outside intelligence research don't think so. They're wrong, but this is such a bone of contention that you can find debates about the debate. I don't want to stray too much. Here's the [question asked on this site](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2758/are-iq-tests-reliable).

#### Are they actually onto something, like PositScience?

No, they're **not** onto something, **like** PositScience.
PositScience is most likely the same, but geared towards the elderly from what I can tell from a cursory glance. They're a bit better at scientific street cred. ie. actually publishing peer-reviewed studies and responding to criticism.
But their studies don't support the strength of their marketing claims and, of course, they selectively leave out studies showing no benefit (by other researchers, but probably they also their own shock-full file drawer) and they have a huge conflict of interest.
Here's [Hal Pashler calling them out](https://twitter.com/search?q=%40hpashler%20positscience&src=typd) and here's [Seth Roberts calling them out](http://blog.sethroberts.net/2013/02/22/questions-for-posit-science/).
The company's responses to those two callouts have been weak, but here's an affiliated author (got only a little money on the side) [dealing well with criticism](http://www.plosone.org/article/comments/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0061624) of a fairly weak study.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your intelligible and well-supported response.

Comment: Would you like to tackle this question too? http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/16161/can-a-person-get-any-more-creative-by-playing-video-games

Comment: while IQ is a decent measure, it's a spot measurement and can change radically over a person's life. Also IQ isn't the same as IQ test scores, which is highly dependent on circumstances during the test as well as test preparation and training (some people are just better at test taking than others, that doesn't mean they're less intelligent).

Comment: @jwenting Mh. I used IQ as a shorthand for IQ test scores, which **can** change radically (think concussion), but usually don't (rank order is preserved, even when it comes to dementia) and is not *highly* dependent on test prep., circumstances and training (of course testing circumstances are held somewhat constant usually). Check your facts, read e.g. Deary 2004.

Comment: have you ever done such tests? It IS possible to train for them, and the score is highly dependent on aptitude for the specific style of testing performed.

Comment: @jwenting Please. I won't challenge your anecdotes with my anecdotes. I gave you a good reference. Or Wikipedia. *g* means that it is not testing-style-specific. But yes, you can learn the results for a specific test by heart (if you're good at memorising, which is *g*-loaded, but I digress), you can practice some stuff. I didn't deny this in the first comment. If you read some of the links I posted, you'll find that one big problem with purported "training transfer effects" is that the training task is too similar to the outcome task. Chat, if you've got further questions, won't debate in c.

Comment: `Psychometricians generally regard IQ tests as having high statistical reliability.[citation needed]` I found that funny - you might want a better source!

Comment: You're quoting a Wikipedia section whose first sentence has a missing reference. The other reference in that section is a self-reference, and a book from 1937.

Comment: [Comments removed/edited. Keep it nice.]

Comment: @ChrisS I link just two things (the reason: this part-question has been aptly answered here already): A Wikipedia article and a question on this site. The answer on this site refers to [an article from an APA task force](http://socrates.berkeley.edu/~maccoun/PP279_Neisser1.pdf) which came to a consensus. That consensus supports my assertions. I gave another ref, Deary 2004, in the comments. Since you're such a helpful spirit, you might want to add these articles as references to the Wikipedia article. I refuse to debate this with you further, because you seem unwilling to assume good faith.